# How can I condense down these if statements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I'd like to reduce the size of this if statement so it can iterate continuously until around 20, with the pattern I have below:

```
    if (i >= 0 && i <= 3) {
        $('.timeline__bar').css({ 
            transform: 'translateX(-0vw)',
        });
    }
    if (i > 3 && i <= 7) {
        $('.timeline__bar').css({ 
            transform: 'translateX(-92vw)',
        });
    }
    if (i > 7 && i <= 11) {
        $('.timeline__bar').css({ 
            transform: 'translateX(-184vw)',
        });
    } 
//ect ect until 20
```

The amount I'm transforming everytime is -92 vh units and I'm sure theres a loop pattern I can hook into too but I'm unsure how to do this.

Comment: Wow inundated with help! Thanks all, now which one is the best answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this

```
function trans(num) {
 $('.timeline__bar').css({ 
    transform: 'translateX(-'+(Math.floor(num/4)*92)+'vw)',
 });
}
```

UPDATE: I was using parseInt, but changed to Math.floor since it is more performant if you loop.

Comment: That is possible. I do not know how often he will call this

Comment: `parseInt` is doing `Math.floor` here? Any other reason to use `parseInt`?

Comment: "shorter than math floor" ... but longer for the cpu: it's needlessly converting the float to a string then parsing the string to a number. Use `Math.floor` as intended or `>> 0`

Comment: There is another answer using Math.floor - but I can update - note: https://jsperf.com/math-floor-vs-math-round-vs-parseint/55 - seems `(num/4 | 0)` is fastest on Chrome in any case

Answer (score 1):

Use `else if` instead of `if` for the last two `if` statements. This will give you a better performance by a tiny bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check this approach and remove the additional checkings from the statements

```
var size;

if (i <= 3 && i > 0) {
    size = '0vw';
} else if (i <= 7) {
    size = '-92vw';
} else if(i <= 11) { 
    size = '-184vw'; 
}

$('.timeline__bar').css({ 
    transform: `translateX(${size})`,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.(inside for loop or wherever you are using that lot's of ifs)

```
j = Math.floor(i/4);
param = "translateX(-" + j*92 + "vw)";
$('.timeline__bar').css({ 
            transform: param,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you look for, where to have an outer check for `>= 0`, and use `else if` within.

By using `else if` instead of separate `if` statements, you only need to check if it is `i <= n`, and when it validates to true, it step into that statement and then step out of the `if/else if` chain.

```
if (i >= 0) {
    if (i <= 3) {
        $('.timeline__bar').css({ 
            transform: 'translateX(-0vw)',
        });
    } else if (i <= 7) {
        $('.timeline__bar').css({ 
            transform: 'translateX(-92vw)',
        });
    } else if (i <= 11) {
        $('.timeline__bar').css({ 
            transform: 'translateX(-184vw)',
        });
    } else if (i <= 15) {
        $('.timeline__bar').css({ 
            transform: 'translateX(-276vw)',
        });
    } else if (i <= 19) {
        $('.timeline__bar').css({ 
            transform: 'translateX(-368vw)',
        });
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you use `if` and `else if`, making it not work unnecessary code. And remove unecessary conditions, which are checked in the previous `if`:

```
if (i >= 0 && i <= 3) {
    $('.timeline__bar').css({ 
        transform: 'translateX(-0vw)',
    });
} else if (i <= 7) { //only one condition here is what you need. :)
    $('.timeline__bar').css({ 
        transform: 'translateX(-92vw)',
    });
} //...
```

To make it "cleaner" you can create a function too:

```
function translateTBar(value){
    $('.timeline__bar').css({ transform: 'translateX(-' + value + 'vw)'});
}

if( i >= 0 && i <= 3) { translateTBar(0); }
else if( i <= 7) { translateTBar(92); }
else if( i <= 11) { translateTBar(184); }
//...
```

Comment: Nice explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Factor out the common code and set a variable and use else if

```
var translateX = '-0vw'
if (i > 3 && i <= 7) {
 translateX = '-92vw'
} else if (i > 7 && i <= 11) {
  translateX = '-184vw'
}

$('.timeline__bar').css({ 
  transform: 'translateX(' + translateX + ')',
});
```